# Do I need two SSL certs when using Cloudflare?

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I inherited this server set up with my job and I'm trying to make sense of it...

Our domain's NS records point to Cloudflare (xxx.xxx.xxx.163). We have a valid cert with them.
Everything looks fine from the browser end and with online cert checkers for this cert.

On Cloudflare, the DNS 'A' record points to 3dCart.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.212). Here's where our web content resides. 
But if I do a DNS lookup, I get the Cloudflare IP (xxx.xxx.xxx.163).
So it looks like the 3dCart server is totally transparent.

We currenlty have a second SSL with the 3dCart's ip (xxx.xxx.xxx.212).

Do we need to have this second cert? 
I don't see how it can ever be accessed

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a question about programming languages?

Comment: When someone hits a CloudFlare site, the request goes user --> CloudFlare --> server. CloudFlare manages the SSL for user --> CF, but you should really have SSL on the server for the CF --> server part.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should have that origin certificate. Cloudflare accesses your origin site securely using that Origin Certificate. However, the Origin Certificate doesn't need to chain to a public root. You can let CloudFlare issue a free certificate from its private root CA or use a self signed certificate for your Origin certificate.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.